# Android Service freezes main UI

Tags: android

In my app there are 2 main functions.

The first is to download some data and display in the main UI. For the downloading portion, i used async task to implement and had no problem.

At the same time I need to so a second task which is to upload some data to backend. As this is an independent task I used a service to implement this. I used code snippet from http://androidsourcecode.blogspot.sg/2010/10/basic-android-background-service.html to do this.

But my main UI freezes when i start the app.

Any idea what's wrong? Is there any other way to implement this? The downloading is a dependent task as the data is then displayed but the uploading is independent.

Comment: *But main UI freezes when i start the app.* => Why? How can we see what you have done in code?

Comment: If you are using `Service` it will freeze the main UI, use instead `Intent Service` which runs in the background

Comment: for more details refer http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidServices/article.html

Answer (score 0):

I started service and then started new Thread that will do all job that I need. Then all job is running not on main thread and it will not freeze application.

Remember that you can also bind service to the activity and call method (that will create Thread) from your activity.